# Custom Framework with Swift and SpriteKit: can't access custom class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-custom-framework

I created my custom framework in `swift`, let says `MyCustomFramework`.

Within this project, I added a new **swift file**: `XYZCustomClass` which looks like this:

```
public class XYZCustomClass: SKNode {
    // variables declaration

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        // make my custom init here
    }

    ...
}
```

I build my project as `iOS Generic Device` and get my `MyCustomFramework.framework` location.

Then I import `MyCustomFramework.framework` within a personal project and I import it in the good file:

```
import SpriteKit
import MyCustomFramework

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {            
        let test = XYZCustomClass()    // Error
    }
}
```

And I finally get the following error:

> "path"/MyProject/GameScene.swift:44:20: XYZCustomClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class

As an additional information, the project has been built with `SpriteKit` in `swift` language.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Check that the framework is included under 'General'->'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' and/or under 'Build Phases'->'Target Dependencies', and add it if necessary.

Comment: The framework is indeed, automatically added to "General/Linked Frameworks" while added to the project. However, "Build Phases/Target Dependencies" only accept : "MyProjectTests" and "MyProjectUITests" as inputs.